# Opening a file using relative path

Tags: c, unix, path

The following code is supposed to work as follows: print the list of the files in a directory, and print the content of each .c file. 
it works fine when executed in UNIX for the same directory: ./a.out ./

However, I was not able to make it work for ./a.out ../differentDir execution.

I know that if the absolute path is provided as an argument, I could use argv[1] for that. However, when it is provided in a form of a relative path I am lost.

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 32768

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    char filename[80];
    int  name_length;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dir_name\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((dp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL ){
           printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
           memset(filename, '\0', sizeof(filename));
           strcpy(filename, dirp->d_name);
           printf(" ** %s ", filename);
           name_length = strlen(filename);
           printf(" name_length=%d \n", name_length);
            if (findC(filename)) // checking if the file has a .c extension
            {
                fp=fopen(filename, "r");
                if (fp == NULL)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open .C file!\n");
                else
                    {// if the file was opened successfuly:
                        do
                        {
                           fgets(buf,BUFFSIZE,fp); // reading each line until buffer is full or until reaching whitespace
                           buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0'; // removing the trailing whitespace from the buffer
                           puts(buf);
                        }
                        while (!feof(fp));
                    printf("\n\n");
                    fclose(fp);
                    }
            }
        }
    closedir(dp);
    return(0);
}

/*FindC method gets a c-string that represents a file name; returns 1 if the file ends with .C extension, else returns 0*/
int findC(char * name)
{
    int len = strlen(name);
    if (len>=2 && name[len-2]=='.' && tolower(name[len-1])=='c')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side issues: `fgets(buf,BUFFSIZE,fp); buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';` can lead to undefined behavior.  1) check result of `fgets()` before using `buf`.   2) Insure `strlen(buf) > 0` before using `buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0'`.  (It is rarely needed, but does prevent UB).

Comment: Thanks, good point! This way it would be better:
if (fgets(buf,BUFFSIZE,fp)!=NULL) 
                           {
                            buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';
                            puts(buf);
                           }

Comment: Code fails because `fopen(filename...` does not consider `argv[1]`.

Comment: Use `buf[strcspn(buf, "\n')] = 0;` to strip potential `\n`.  `buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0';` still fails for #2 in above comment.

Comment: that's the problem I mentioned. If my executable is in the same directory, it works fine. However if I want to print another directory, I need to get somehow the absolute path. The realpath() method does not work for me for some reason (see my reply to @Dac Saunders).

Comment: "need to get somehow the absolute path" is one way.  Another is to form the relative path/filename with a `argv[1]` `/` `filename` concatenation.

Comment: But in case the file invoked with a relative path, the argv[1] will include something like "../dirname", wouldn't it?

Comment: Then open file "../dirname/cfile.c"

Comment: I was under the impression that fopen would work only with an absolute path, therefore dismissed the concatenation idea. I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123083/discussion-between-dr29-and-chux).

Answer (score 1):

Upon opening the file to read, the file pathname needs to also be relative.

```
    // Form prefix for complete relative file name
    char filename[MAXPATH];
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    // append '/' if directory path does not end in '/'
    if (TBD_code(filename)) {
      strcat(filename, "/");
    }
    char *end = filename[strlen(filename)];

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL ){
       printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
       if (findC(dirp->d_name)) {
         // append filename to prefix
         strcpy(end, dirp->d_name);
         fp=fopen(filename, "r");
         ...
```

Comment: I followed your recommendation with a similar version, however when I run it on a relative path it fails to open the files. The output for $ ./lsc ../dir

`** .  name_length=1
..
 ** ..  name_length=2
b.html
 ** b.html  name_length=6
practice.txt
 ** practice.txt  name_length=12
A.c
 ** A.c  name_length=3
Can't open .C file!
`

Comment: @DR29 What is the value of `filename` when `fp=fopen(filename, "r");` fails?

Comment: "../dir/file.txt" is the value (I've added a puts statement to verify that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `realpath(argv1...)` like in this example. `realpath` will return the absolute path for a relative path.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *path = "../..";
    char buff[PATH_MAX + 1]; /* not sure about the "+ 1" */
    char *res = realpath(path, buff);
    if (res) {
        printf("This source is at %s.\n", buff);
    } else {
        perror("realpath");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To include the desired behavior in your program, you can use `realpath`in your code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 32768

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    char filename[80];
    int  name_length;
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[PATH_MAX + 1]; /* not sure about the "+ 1" */

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dir_name\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    char *res = realpath(argv[1], buff);
    if ((dp = opendir(res)) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL ){
        printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
        memset(filename, '\0', sizeof(filename));
        strcpy(filename, dirp->d_name);
        printf(" ** %s ", filename);
        name_length = strlen(filename);
        printf(" name_length=%d \n", name_length);
        if (findC(filename)) // checking if the file has a .c extension
        {
            fp=fopen(filename, "r");
            if (fp == NULL)
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't open .C file!\n");
            else
            {// if the file was opened successfuly:
                do
                {
                    fgets(buf,BUFFSIZE,fp); // reading each line until buffer is full or until reaching whitespace
                    buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0'; // removing the trailing whitespace from the buffer
                    puts(buf);
                }
                while (!feof(fp));
                printf("\n\n");
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return(0);
}

/*FindC method gets a c-string that represents a file name; returns 1 if the file ends with .C extension, else returns 0*/
int findC(char * name)
{
    int len = strlen(name);
    if (len>=2 && name[len-2]=='.' && tolower(name[len-1])=='c')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what's wrong with it, but when I compile I get "undefined reference to realpath".

Comment: @DR29 It can depend on your environment and os. I tested it with Ubuntu Linux. Did you include the `stdlib.h` ?

Comment: Yes I did. I am actually writing it on Windows and trying to run the code on a unix ssh server.

Comment: What language standard defines `realpath()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could first change to the directory `chdir` either with relative or absolute path and the get the absolute path via the `getcwd`

```c
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 32768
#define PATH_SIZE 512

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    char path[PATH_SIZE];
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    char filename[80];
    int  name_length, r;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dir_name\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    strcpy(path, argv[1]);
    r = chdir(path);
    if( r != 0 )
    {
        printf("Invalid path '%s'\n",path);
        exit(1);
    }
    getcwd(path,PATH_SIZE);

    if ((dp = opendir(path)) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL ){
           printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
           memset(filename, '\0', sizeof(filename));
           strcpy(filename, dirp->d_name);
           printf(" ** %s ", filename);
           name_length = strlen(filename);
           printf(" name_length=%d \n", name_length);
            if (findC(filename)) // checking if the file has a .c extension
            {
                fp=fopen(filename, "r");
                if (fp == NULL)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open .C file!\n");
                else
                    {// if the file was opened successfuly:
                        do
                        {
                           fgets(buf,BUFFSIZE,fp); // reading each line until buffer is full or until reaching whitespace
                           buf[strlen(buf)-1]='\0'; // removing the trailing whitespace from the buffer
                           puts(buf);
                        }
                        while (!feof(fp));
                    printf("\n\n");
                    fclose(fp);
                    }
            }
        }
    closedir(dp);
    return(0);
}

/*FindC method gets a c-string that represents a file name; returns 1 if the file ends with .C extension, else returns 0*/
int findC(char * name)
{
    int len = strlen(name);
    if (len>=2 && name[len-2]=='.' && tolower(name[len-1])=='c')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```